# After data augmentation - can't use from_tensor_slices

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I got the following error while working on ~ 200MB of data : `ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.`

I'm working on google colab. At the beginning my data set had 4415 images of animals ~ 120MB :

```
!ls -l /content/Dataset/train/real | wc -l
!du -sh /content/Dataset/train/real
4415 
156M    /content/Dataset/train/real
```

I tried to do some data augmentation to create more images. After the data augmentation flow the dir that contains the images was doubled :

```
!ls -l /content/Dataset/train/real | wc -l
!du -sh /content/Dataset/train/real
8829
300M    /content/Dataset/train/real
```

I loading the images with opencv and afterwards I'm passing them to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` as a numpy array:

```
def load_images(dir):
  images = []
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for image in files:
      img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root,image))
      if len(img.shape) == 3:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) / 255
        images.append(img)
  return np.asarray(images, dtype= np.float32)

images= load_images("Dataset/train/real")
BUFFER_SIZE = len(train_images)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(32)
```

I'm getting the following error on the last row :

```
    518     if nparray.size * nparray.itemsize >= (1 << 31):
    519       raise ValueError(
--> 520           "Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.")
    521     tensor_proto.tensor_content = nparray.tostring()
    522     return tensor_proto

ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_tensor_slices` encodes the data as a constant in the graph. Because of implementation constraints from protobuf, the graph itself can't contain tensors that are too big (your decoded image data), which is what your error is telling you.

You need to change the pipeline to instead load the images dynamically.
For example (image parsing taken from [TF's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#preprocessing_data)):

```
def parse_image(filename):
  parts = tf.strings.split(filename, '/')
  label = parts[-2]

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
  return image, label

ds = (tf.data.Dataset.list_files(image_dir+'/*.jpg')
      .map(parse_image)
     # ... rest of operations on the image here (shuffling, batching, etc
     )
```

---

## Update

> Hey, can u explain the diff between the solution I used and the one u suggested ? In both cases I will hold a big tensor in memory..

Yes. The error you get is not a memory error, you're not running out of memory to store the images. The problem is linked to Tensorflow's underlying implementation of the operations you perform.

The network **and the input pipline** (and other training stuff like optimizer, etc) are **saved in the Graph protobuf message**. Specifically, when you call `from_tensor_slices([1,2,3,4,5])`, Tensorflow under the hood generates a **constant** tensor containing the data you pass in (`[1,2,3,4,5]`). This tensor is itself a protobuf message containing the data encoded as a string of bytes. However, because of implementation constraints, protobuf messages can't be bigger than a certain size. This means, because `images` is so big, protobuf fails and you get the error.

Now, for the second approach, you don't store the *images* in the network. The pipeline only says "lookin this folder, list all files that are JPEGs and **at runtime** load and decode them". The only "constant" data that needs to be serialized in a protobuf message is the path to the folder, since you're not storing the whole dataset as a constant anymore.

Comment: but my tensor shouldnt be that big, we are talking here on 200MB of images ~ 8k images in my dataset

Comment: Encoded images are much lighter than decoded RGB arrays. 200 MBs on-disk JPEGs are a lot bigger once you treat them as image tensors

Comment: Hey, can u explain the diff between the solution I used and the one u suggested ? In both cases I will hold a big tensor in memory..

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clear explanation. I took your solution and realized that it reads the jpeg with one channel (I want to display the image so I need 3 channels). So I changed the decode_jpeg but still it seems that when I try to draw it with plt.imgshow(ds[0][1]) I'm getting an exception : TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Comment: You'll probably need to change the image decoding function quite a bit, I just took the one from TF's guide as an example, I don't know if it applies to your case. Also, you can't print the image with `pyplot`. You're not *actually* loading the image, just describing how Tesorflow will need to process the data when running the pipeline. Look up input pipelines build with the `tf.data.*` API, it's not exactly trivial

Comment: I see. When exactly during tuntime the images will be loaded ? At the moment I'll try iterate over the dataset ?

Comment: Yes, whenever you iterate over the dataset, the whole pipeline produces the next output (which may have bee prepared already if you `prefetch` data. As I said, pretty complex topic, lots of possibilities there)

Comment: last question if its ok, When I try to describe the shape of each element in the data set I get : 32, 140, 320, 3. My pictures` size is 140x320 and I got 3 channels, but what is the 32 ?

Comment: That's the batch size

Comment: the shape of the train_dataset will be chaned in runtime when the images will be needed ? because If I check the shape of it after the initialization I'm getting : <BatchDataset shapes: ((None, None, None, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.string)>

Comment: I see. Another question if its ok , The map func will work on each cell once(the first time I run over that cell) ? If I want to apply color shifting on the images, I can apply it with map but I'll want to apply the color shiffting every epoch..

Comment: GPhilo and what is the recommended way, if you have data in RAM and not on disk? Storing it to disk would seem silly...

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev Assuming you're using TF 2, you should be able to use from_tensor_slices now (they changed the way things work massively since I wrote that answer), but I can't check right now or know for sure, I'd be curious to know if it works out for you if you try though!

Comment: I think there's also the possibility to use a generator as the data source with from_generator, so if the tensor_slices method gives you problems, write a small generator that returns the items already in memory and use that as source

Comment: @GPhilo No no, it's not working with TF2 even up to nightly (2.5). Trying to send big tokenized text to TPU and getting this problem.

Comment: Cool! Good to know then, thanks! I hope the generator approach will help then :)

Comment: @GPhilo FYI. Generator approach does not work with TPUs (causing infamous "Failed to connect to all addresses" TF error which has no clear resolution yet), whereas from_tensor_slices works, but only on small datasets. dead end.

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev hmm interesting. I guess for now the only solution really is to write the data to disk and read it back with an input pipeline

Comment: Yes that's what tf team recommended, actually. Trying it now. But it should not be that way, I think. Someone is doing his job not well enough )